# Tools: Make Flag/Close More Prominent

Tags: discussion, feature-request, 10k-tools

[image]

It is a little confusing, for instance, on the Tools section (10K+ users only), whether this question was flagged or closed. Normally, exact duplicates would show, in parens the number of close votes. But if you were to click on this example, it does not show a close vote for exact duplicate. So am I to assume it was flagged or a close vote?

I am proposing that the text associated with the "flagged questions" be something like:

flagged (n) : exact duplicate of URL

where `n` is the number of flags.

I have also seen it where questions are flagged `off topic; belongs on superuser/serverfault/etc`. I go into Close Question and there is no close reason, so it must of been flagged? I don't know, I'm not sure.

It is a really confusing interface sometimes.

Comment: The question has been flagged as being a duplicate. If it were not flagged, you would not see it in the "flags" section.

Comment: What? I honestly don't understand the question or what you're asking to be changed here.

Comment: @Cody: Sorry, I must of been tired when I wrote it. Basically, if a question is flagged and requested to be closed, you don't know if the flag is related to the close reason or just that it was flagged that way. The reason is because the Close UI and the Flag UI re-use the same elements. I am proposing that the flags and close reasons be more prominently differentiated.

Comment: The close UI and flag UI **do not** use the same elements. I don't understand what that means. Are you saying that people might literally type `exact duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/3719502` in the "other" box? That's not a problem either, because flags with free-form comments are only shown to moderators.

Comment: @Cody: 10K users can see it too.. I don't know if you can see this but this question is flagged exact duplicate of but the close shows no exact duplicate x 1 close reason (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644081/wpf-usercontrol-dependency-property-setter-not-triggering), but the flag shows it. And they do re-use the same UI, especially if you go to "it doesn't belong here".

Comment: Someone flagged it as a possible duplicate. That has nothing to do with casting a close vote.

Comment: @Cody: You are missing the point. Do I click close or flag? It's confusing. Why not just put the word "flagged:" or "closed:" next to the text rather than being so ambiguous.

Comment: You click whichever one you think is appropriate. I don't understand how it's confusing. If you *agree* that it's a duplicate, you click "close". If you think there's something else wrong, you click "flag". If you think there's nothing wrong at all, you click "flag" and select "invalid flag".

Comment: @Cody: If I think it is a duplicate, then I have to copy the stupid link and then paste it into the UI rather than it being already one of the close reasons. How annoying. The 10K tools needs some more work.

Comment: That's a different issue than the one you present here. That one, I agree with.

Comment: @Cody: Not to mention that when you go to a question that has been flagged "off topic", it automatically takes you over to the Close screen and you vote to close, not flag. How strange.